# How to implement a label button with underlined text on active

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've inserted two labels into my view. When I click one of the labels, I would like to run some code-behind (changing a subview) and the text in the label should be underlined.

How should this be implemented in Cocoa?

Comment: You might try grabbing the button's `titleLabel` property and then setting the label's `attributedText`.

Comment: When will the attributedText be used?

Comment: Actually, not sure why I went off on this tangent...see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass NSTextField and implement its mouseDown: event as

```
@interface ClickableLabel : NSTextField

@end


@implementation ClickableLabel

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: [self stringValue]];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length]);

    [attrString beginEditing];

    // make the text appear with an underline
   [attrString addAttribute: NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSSingleUnderlineStyle] range:range];

   [attrString endEditing];

   [self setAttributedStringValue:attrString];

   [attrString release];
}

@end
```

Set this `ClickableLabel` as your label's class

Answer (score 0):

To have underlined text in the label, set its `attributedText` property. So you can do something like:

```
- (void)underlineRange:(NSRange)range forLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
   NSMutableAttributedString *aText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:label.text];
   [aText addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:range];
   label.attributedText = aText;
}
```

As an aside, when I wrote the comment above, I thought you wanted to underline text on a `UIButton`. There's a more straightforward way of doing so, use `UIButton`'s `setAttributedTitle:forState` method.